# CSS / NavMenu suddenly stopped working on my Blazor App on Chrome

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio-code, blazor

I was working on different apps on my Visual Studio Code, so i was debugging two different applications. However, the CSS effects and NavMenue suddenly disappear from on of them and when I debugged it, I got like the following picture.

[image]

In the debugge console i got this :

[image]

I've not changed anything in the code. Does anyone know what is the reason and how can I solve it ?

Note: when I open the local host from different browser it works well

Comment: If they where on the same port you may have to CTRL-F5 the browser to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

**I've solved the issue by Clearing the Last hour browsing data from Chrome.**

This includes Deleting the following:

- Browsing History.
- Cookies and Other sites.
- Cached Images and Files.

Then everything works well!

**Note**: Ctrl F5 doesn't work so it is better to delete the above information and then try again.